# invalid url for nextjs image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am writing the frontend of my application with nextjs

I am trying to load image from the public folder but I am getting invalid url

I copied the image to the public folder with the name close.png

I tried to access the image with the following code

```
 import Image from "next/image";

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div className="__nav">
      <Image src="/close.png" width={50} height={50} alt="logo" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

I get invalid url.

Error Message

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/Components/NoAuthArea/Nav". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: /close.png
    at onParseError (internal/url.js:279:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (internal/url.js:355:5)
    at imgixLoader (C:\Users\OSHABZ\Documents\My jobs\findahouse\.next\server\chunks\675.js:516:17)
    at defaultImageLoader (C:\Users\OSHABZ\Documents\My jobs\findahouse\.next\server\chunks\675.js:234:16)
    at C:\Users\OSHABZ\Documents\My jobs\findahouse\.next\server\chunks\675.js:203:39
```

Close Image

[image]

How do I solve this problem

Comment: try deleting the build folder and rerun `npm build`

Comment: What does your `next.config.js` look like?

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using nextjs image.
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Example:

```
import Image from "next/image"

<Image src="/close.png" width={200} height={200} />
```

Comment: I also tried that and I am getting the same error

Comment: this way does it work localhost?

Comment: no it does not work on localhost at all

Comment: can you add the error message

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: `/Components/NoAuthArea/Nav` can you post the content? there is no ssr function in it right?

Comment: Any chance to upload the image of the `/Components/NoAuthArea/Nav path?`

Comment: I have updated my question and uploaded the close image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240511/discussion-between-etranz-and-gucal).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you resolved your error, but you should check out the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images) about recommended static imports.

```
import profilePic from '../public/me.png'
```